# Webpack 4, exclude 3rd party lib from minification/compression

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have the following in my config:

```
const viewerConfigProdWeb = merge(common.commonWebConfig, {
output: {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: common.bundleNameWeb
},
devtool: 'source-map',
mode: 'production',
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: false,    //<--- if enabled, causes errors
                ecma: 6,
                mangle: true,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '../js/vendor/tomtom.min.js'),    // <--- it is already minified, want to exclude it somehow. But this approach doesn't work =(
            }
        })
    ]
}
});
```

I'm getting runtime errors when I change 'compress' to true in uglifyOptions. These errors appear when webpack tries to optimize a third-party lib, which is already compressed and minified. How can I exclude it from optimization?

Update: according to Sin's answer and [readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#options), changed the optimization section in the config to following:

```
    optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            exclude: /\.min\.js$/,     //<---- moved up and used regex
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: true,        //<---- still causes errors when enabled
                ecma: 6,
                mangle: true
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

This doesn't work either =( Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for a while, finally found that the `exclude` option only inspects the output filename instead of source filename. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/21) addressing this.
You may try the solutions provided by @hulkish there.

---

Original Answer (not working):

Try add `exclude` to the top level of UglifyJsPlugin options. And use a `RegExp` or Array of `RegExp` instead of the full path. See [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#options)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't work for me either =(

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Currently I've switched to another library which doesn't have this problem. If I face it again, I'll try the solution described in the issue.